# how to make iphone apps like ibeer, imilk, ibug, ibeer

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I was visiting [this website](http://www.hottrixdownload.com/iphone/) with cool animated apps. I was wondering how's the easiest way of building a app like those. I almost bet it uses some kind of OpenGL ES.

Is it a good case of [cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org/) usage?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Yes you can make those kinds of apps...

Comment: I know I can because they exist. My question is _how_ :)

Comment: Generally, if you have to ask if you should use cocos2d, then you probably should be using it. It's a fairly powerful library, aimed at beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that many of these apps are possible to create using the Core Animation Cocoa framework. I couldn't say for sure if those apps use that technology, but it seems like 2d animation would be sufficient. The coin animation seems like a perfect fit.

You'd need to create the artwork for any animation frames that aren't the result of rotating or moving an image. Core Animation does a great job animating the movement of 2d images. The movement of bubbles in liquid could probably be done easiest by cycling between some artwork animating them.

That said, it's a trade-off between creating lots of artwork and writing some OpenGL or Quartz code to simulate the appearance of liquid (or whatever).

Check out this [guide to Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to see the possibilities.