# API's used in iBeer and iMunchies iPhone Applications

Tags: ios, emoji

I just wanted to ask you if you have some idea about which API's or techniques were used in iBeer and iMunchies applications? These applications are not useful (in my personal opinion), but does have some cool effects.

Theories are welcome :). Just trying to gain some knowledge.

Comment: You need to detail what you are asking about in your question. Just mentioning an app and saying "how to they do it" isn't a helpful question. If there's a specific effect, describe the effect, provide a screenshot if possible, and ask how that specific effect is done.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885152/how-to-make-iphone-apps-like-ibeer-imilk-ibug-ibeer

Comment: @U62: The basic effect that all of these apps use is the drinking effect, and that's what i'm interested in. I'll try to be more specific next time :) Thanks.

@Brad: Thanks for pointing me to a similar thread. I saw that post after posting the question :D Guess i should search before posting new questions : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is they use OpenGL and/or Core Animation. I've never done anything like that before though.